# How to show that $C^{\infty} (X) \otimes C^{\infty} (X) \not\simeq C^{\infty} (X \times X)$ as vector spaces.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. Then as vector spaces $$C^{\infty} (X) \otimes C^{\infty} (X) \not\simeq C^{\infty} (X \times X).$$

I know that there is a map from the algebraic tensor product $C^{\infty} (X) \otimes C^{\infty} (X) \longrightarrow C^{\infty} (X \times X)$ defined on elementary tensors by $f \otimes g \mapsto (h : (x,y) \mapsto f(x) g(y))$ and then extend it to the whole of the algebraic tensor product $C^{\infty} (X) \otimes C^{\infty} (X)$ by imposing linearity. But I can't conclude injectivity and surjectivity of this map. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The title asks a different question than the one in the body — the latter asks «why is not the canonical (?) map an isomorphism» and is the more sensible one.

Comment: If $X$ is $0$-dimensional and compact then the map *is* an isomorphism.

Comment: Doesn’t your most recent question about $\sin(xy)$ show this is wrong?

Comment: @TedShifrin$:$ We only show that $C^{\infty} (\mathbb R) \otimes C^{\infty} (\mathbb R) \simeq C^{\infty} (\mathbb R^2).$

Comment: You mean $\not\cong$. Does that not suffice? It can't hold for a general manifold $X$ if it fails for $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @TedShifrin why is that true?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$Let $M$ be your $X$.

If $f:M\times M\to\RR$ is a function, for each $y\in M$ we may consider the function $f_y:x\in M\mapsto f(x,y)\in\RR$, which is a smooth function, and the subspace $V_f$ of $C^\infty(M)$ generated by $\{f_y:y\in M\}$.

If $f$ is in the image of the canonical map $C^\infty(M)\otimes C^\infty(M)\to C^\infty$, then $V_f$ is finite-dimensional.

To prove that your map is not surjective, then, it is enough to find a smooth function $f:M\times M\to\RR$ such that $V_f$ is not finite dimensional.

We may just as well look for such function with support contained in an open set of the form $U\times U$ with $U$ domain of a coordinate patch of $M$, and this reduces the problem to finding a function $f$ of compact support on $\RR^n\times\RR^n$ whose $V_f$ is not finite dimensional, and one can do this with the same idea as for $\sin(xy)$, times a bump function.

---

On the other hand, the map is injective. Suppose that $u=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i\otimes g_i$ is mapped to zero. We may suppose that the $n$ functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are linearly independent. We have that $\sum_if_i(x)g_i(y)=0$ for all choices of $x$ and $y$ in $M$. If $u$ is not zero, then there is a $j$ and a $y_0$ such that $g_j(y_0)\neq0$. We have that $\sum_if_i(x)g_i(y_0)=0$ for all $x$, and this is a non-trivial linear relation among the $f_i$, which is absurd.

Comment: Just a comment. will be interesting to extend and see if  for $Y = C^{\infty}(X) \times C^{\infty}(X)$,  $Z = C^{\infty}(X \times X)$, whether completion of $Y$ is same as completion of $Z$ w.r.t to some norm. In this case the same proof may not work.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a proof that no norm works in this space ?

Comment: Why do we need to find a function $f \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n)$ to be of compact support?

Comment: In case of $\mathbb R^n$ does the function $(x_1, \cdots, x_n, y_1, \cdots, y_n) \mapsto \sin \left (\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} x_i y_i \right )$ hold good?